# How to communicate with a background activity from intent service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intentservice

So I have a Activity which is holding some data MyData. I have a background IntentService which runs periodically and updates data in database which I like to reload when background activity comes to foreground. However I want to reload only when background Service ran. I used broadcast receivers but those work only if the Activity is in Foreground. It doesn't receive any events if Activity is in background.

Another way I am thinking is to write a flag "reload" in preferences when my IntentService runs and then when backgrounded Activity resumes then it checks that flag and reloads if necessary and set it to false again.

Can anyone suggest a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way? Use a static method, something like `MyIntentService.didAnythingChange()` (making sure to clear that flag when the activity reloads). Or maybe a sequence number, so you'd have something like `if (this.updateNo != MyIntentService.getLatestUpdateNo())` in your Activity.

The complicated way? Use a dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver in your Activity, and send a matching broadcast from your IntentService. Let the BroadcastReceiver set a flag in the activity.